# response header support for Content-Language

Tags: css, http-headers, response, multilingual, lang

Does IE7 and Google Chrome support the response header "Content-Language"? I am setting this in my application in to the response header for page requests. The header is recognised in ie8, ie9 and FF4 where the following css trick works:

```
h1:lang(en) { font-weight: bold; }
h1:lang(es) { font-weight: normal; color: #FF0000; }
```

However in IE7 and chrome, the css is not applied to particular elements.

Comment: Consider adding the lang attribute to your HTML and basing your CSS from that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This article might be helpful for you: http://rishida.net/blog/?p=67.

According to the author, the :lang selector is not supported by IE7. "h1[lang |= 'es']" should work, but you have to set the lang attribute on each h1 element - you can't rely on the Content-Language. However, :lang is support to be supported in Chrome for at least versions 2 and onward. Can you dynamically change the lang attribute on your html element as well?

Answer (score 0):

It's not supported in IE7, not sure about chrome.

**EDIT**

I just ran a test on Chrome 11 for windows and it was supported.